# Allegory? - "Someone once told me they have one too many consonants on their welcome sign."

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is from a comment [hereunder](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/big-spender-tries-to-leave-98-931-87-tip-for-7-sandwich-1.2890331) (NOT the actual article). For brevity, denote [U1:] as user 1.

> [U1:] **Sentient Human**
>
> I'd drink too if I lived in Angus. LOL
>
> [U2:] **Dolosus**
>
> @Sentient Human: Someone once told me they have one too many consonants
>   on their welcome sign.
>
> [U3:] **Iknewthat**
>
> @Dolosus Ouch!
>
> [U4:] **Sgtronb**
>
> @Dolosus Many times the "G" has been painted over on this sign, its
>   just plain funny to see.

Please confirm if [allegory](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/164823/50720)'s the right word? I can infer U1's condescension towards people who live in Angus, Ontario, which U1 alleges is an insipid town. However, please explain the allegories afterwards? I  recognise that U2 intended figurativeness **(Is the correct term [subtext](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31083/50720)**)?  of his sentence, because U3's 'Ouch!' implies that U2 mordantly riposted to U1. Yet is U4's comment related to the foregoing; I do recognise that without a g, 'Angus' becomes 'Anus'?

Comment: *Allegory* is not the right word; consult a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/allegory). This is crude [wordplay](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wordplay).

Comment: @StoneyB I'd agree that it's crude in tone, but I personally don't think it's crude in technique.  It's not terribly clever either, but it's more sophisticated than "Heh, more like Anus."  Just clarifying my perception of the crudity of the comment. :)

Comment: Does the town also take the *g* out of *welcome sign*?

Comment: @JimReynolds I don't know, but I remain mystified.

Comment: U4's comment says that lots of people have actually removed the *g* on the sign by painting over it as joke/prank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allegory is definitely the wrong word. An allegory is a symbolic story, and this is not a story. It's not subtext either since the meaning isn't hidden.

What U2 said is just a joke. I don't think there's a special word for this kind of joke, although humor involving missing letters in signs is [common](http://www.collegehumor.com/post/6770146/20-signs-missing-important-letters).

EDIT: Here's a "translation" that shows what each user's comment means.

> U1: Living in Angus is very unpleasant. If I lived there, the pain would drive me to alcoholism.
>
> U2: The "Welcome to Angus" sign should say "Welcome to Anus", because Angus is a shitty town.
>
> U3: That was a harsh joke, U2! [This does not imply disagreement with the joke.]
>
> U4: U2, that's not just a joke. Sometimes people really do paint over the welcome sign outside of town to make it say "Welcome to An us". I find this funny whenever it happens.

Comment: Thanks, but did you explain this sequence of rejoinders? I ask not only about the right terms, but about the meaning?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I've updated my answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively! Yes; I cherish your edit particularly because I did misinterpret the jokes in my OP.